# How to change the TimePicker interval in element UI

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, element-ui

May I ask if the preset minute interval of the TimePicker in element UI is every minute, how to change it to every 10 minutes as an interval? I hope to get your help, it is quite distressing. thanks

```
[element UI][1] 
https://element.eleme.io/#/zh-CN/component/time-picker


[myCode][2]
https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/abKqpZY


  [1]: https://element.eleme.io/#/zh-CN/component/time-picker
  [2]: https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/abKqpZY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The focus method of the component can be called with refs

```
   <el-time-select
  v-model="value"
  :picker-options="{
    start: '08:30',
    step: '00:10',
    end: '18:30'
  }"
refs="timePicker"
  placeholder="Select time">
</el-time-select>

 this.$refs.timePicker.focus()
```

Comment: 你好，你也是亞洲人嗎?哈哈
謝謝你的回覆，不過我這邊使用的組件名為 el-time-picker 你的範例使用的是 el-time-select 那這樣的方法是行得通的嗎?

Comment: https://element.eleme.io/#/zh-CN/component/time-picker 可以的，可以看下这个文档,method就是可以通过refs调用组件内置方法

Comment: 謝謝你的幫助，在這邊遇到華人感覺很新鮮

Comment: 不客气～哈哈哈，我也感覺很新鮮

Answer (score 0):

the documentation you showed actually clearly shows how to implement it.
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/time-picker#timepicker

So you can use the picker-options prop and use the 'step' property for custom intervals

```js
<el-time-select
  v-model="value"
  :picker-options="{
    start: '08:30',
    step: '00:10',
    end: '18:30'
  }"
  placeholder="Select time">
</el-time-select>
```

Comment: Hello, but I am using el-time-picker instead of el-time-select , can this be modified?

Comment: Seems like that's mot really an option. One hack could be to just use two drop downs for hours and minutes and then use a computed property to combine the two into a time format.